# Stirling numbers of the second kind recursion proof by calculating in how many ways the split can be made so that number 1 is in its own section

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$S(n, k) = S(n − 1, k - 1) + kS(n − 1, k)$

I am having trouble understanding where the formula above comes from. I found several explanations online but find them difficult to understand. I tried using the formula with S(6, 3) for example, and can see that it works.

A teacher suggested to approach it by thinking about how many ways 1 is in its own segment when a set {1, 2, ... n} is split.

I calculated this for various combinations but I don't see a pattern or understand why I would go about it this way.

This is the proof I found online: "Given a partition of [n − 1], there are 2 ways to construct a partition of [n] with k
subsets: either by adding n into a part of a partition of [n − 1] with k subsets or by adding
the set {n} as a new part into a partition of [n − 1] with k − 1 subsets."

If there is a simpler way of proving (or explaining) this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first half of the equation refers to some $x \in \{1,...,n\}$ (but let $x$ be the $n$th term, for simplicity) in a singleton set, and the number of ways to pick all the rest of the $k-1$ elements, but you only have $n-1$ choices, since $x$ was already determined. You do this because when you add another element, you must consider the singleton.

The second half of the equation is how to partition an $n-1$ element set into $k$ different blocks. But you still have to multiply by $k$ in order to account for $k$ choices of where $x$ goes in the partition.

Comment: Combinatorial arguments are somewhat difficult for me to write, so if this is unclear, let me know.

Comment: The wording of the first part was a bit difficult to understand at first. I now understand though that x is in a group by itself and only n - 1 elements are left to divide into k - 1 groups.